# Just a bunch of dudes

Tags: riddle, word

My prefix is dude.

My infix is little dude.

My suffix is too loud, dude.

I'm a stand-up dude.

Comment: That's a very, very good riddle, dude!

Comment: Obviously you're [Jeff Bridges](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118715) ;-)

Comment: Dude, this is radical.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> Paladin

My prefix is dude.

> Pal

My infix is little dude.

> Lad

My suffix is too loud, dude.

> Din

I'm a stand-up dude.

> A paladin was a knight renowned for heroism and chivalry

Comment: What's the reasoning behind the Too Loud part?

Comment: @Orphevs A din is defined as a loud, unpleasant and prolonged noise.