# This Riley is a servant of truth

Tags: riddle

> My prefix is a trusted mate.
>    My suffix, cause for neighbors' hate.
>    My infix is a cheerful youth.
>   My whole is a powerful servant of truth.

What am I?

Comment: Is this considered a [duplicate?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/63769/46277)

Comment: HA! I didn't think to look up the answer. The original one is way funnier.

Comment: [When should riddles be considered duplicates?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5665) has some relevant guidance here.  I think this meets the threshold for being considered  duplicate.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. By this logic, every poem in the praise of a rose would be called a duplicate, and [every](https://www.poets.org/poetsorg/poem/nightingale) other [ode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ode_to_a_Nightingale) to a [nightingale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nightingale:_A_Conversation_Poem) would be mere plagiarism. One would assume that all journeys and paths to a common destination are not identical.

Comment: Thanks for the note, @Rubio. And I agree with the title change, I like it far better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it might be this

> Paladin

My prefix is a trusted mate.

> Pal

My suffix, cause for neighbors' hate.

> Din, a loud, unpleasant, and prolonged noise.

My infix is a cheerful youth.

> Lad

Comment: Yeah, I think this one was a little too easy. Great job!

Comment: My first accepted answer!