# Just a bunch of dudes too

Tags: riddle, word

A word was clued, then split into three fixes, which three other dudes clued. The clues are:

> I'm a sailor dude,
>   I'm a generic dude,
>   I'm an original dude,
>   I'm used on road trips.

<sub>Inspired by **[Just a bunch of dudes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/63769/just-a-bunch-of-dudes)**</sub>

Comment: Inspiration [just keeps going](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/97833/5373) :-)

Comment: @Rand, I meant to subvert the riley by disordering the clues, then on posting review, ordered by length, and by happenstance this ordered the riley correctly!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a little thought, could you be:

> **TARMACADAM**? (Usually shortened to 'tarmac'...)

*I'm a sailor dude,*

> **TAR** is another word for sailor, often used in cryptic crosswords.

*I'm a generic dude,*

> **MAC** is a common nickname or moniker by which a man may be addressed.

*I'm an original dude*,

> In religious circles, **ADAM** is the name given to the first ('*original*') man.

*I'm used on road trips.*

> **TARMACADAM** (tarmac) is what a road surface is made of - it actually **is** the road!

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes more sense. Well done!

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is

> Tarpaulin

I'm a sailor dude,

> **Tar** = a sailor

I'm a generic dude,

> **Paul** = a common male forename

I'm an original dude,

> **In** = fashionable or original (the "in" thing)

I'm used on road trips.

> **Tarpaulin** = heavy-duty waterproof cloth, often used outdoors on trips.

Comment: Just pipped me to the (quite literal!) post - nice work +1 :)

Comment: @Stiv & hexomino , excellent as always, but there's a different answer.

Comment: @Tom No way! I was utterly convinced this was it. However, I'm sure when someone finds the true answer I will be even more convinced by that, as usual :)