# Splitting a road trip into four

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

A word is clued, and four parts of it (in order, but possibly overlapping) are also clued. The five clues are:

> I'm not for hands.
>   I'm on this site.
>   I'm full of anger.
>   I'm full of anger.
>   I'm used on road trips.

What is the word?

Comment: Inspired by [Just a bunch of dudes too](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/97831/5373), which was in turn inspired by [Just a bunch of dudes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/63769/17).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I want to say

> automobile

I don't like the overlaps for the second clue with my current explanation.

I'm not for hands.

> auto
>   as in automatic, as in not manual, as in not by hand.

I'm on this site.

> tom
>   currently sixth ranked user on this site, by reputation.  (OP is #1)

I'm full of anger.

> mob
>   a group of angry people

I'm full of anger.

> bile
>   a digestive secretion associated with ill humor

I'm used on road trips.

> automobile
>   as in a car.

Comment: That's the correct answer! But the first clue is not correct. For the second clue, maybe I'll add a hint later, or someone might guide you in the right direction ;-)

Comment: Great, now you've got everything. I'll mark this answer as correct (at some point - I'm often quite slow to accept).